# React Navigation with Redux - Drawer close error

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'am using react navigation with redux and after redux integration, i got some errors on drawer close.

[image]

```
import React from "react";
. . .
import { NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
import { StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import { addListener } from "./components/common/utils";
import Dashboard from './components/pages/Dashboard';
. . .
const MainNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Dashboard : {
    screen : Dashboard,
  },
  . . .
})

export const AppNavigator = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Main: { screen: MainNavigator }
  }, {
    contentComponent: Menu,
    drawerWidth: 300,
    headerMode: 'screen',
    drawerPosition: 'left',
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
  }
)

class AppWithNavigationState extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.onBackPress = this.onBackPress.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackPress)
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackPress)
  }

  onBackPress () {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    const { dispatch, nav } = this.props;
    return (
      <AppNavigator
        navigation={{
          dispatch,
          state: nav,
          addListener,
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  nav: state.nav,
});

AppWithNavigationState.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  nav: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppWithNavigationState);
```

Here is my reducer:

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import { AppNavigator } from "../../App";
import {...} from './constants';
import { ToastAndroid } from 'react-native';

const mainAction = AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Main');
const initialNavState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(mainAction);

function nav(state = initialNavState, action) {
  let nextState;
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'Reports':
      nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
        NavigationActions.back(),
        state
      );
      break;
    default:
      nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
      break;
  }
  return nextState || state;
}

const initialState = fromJS({
  isLoading: true,
  ...
});

function store(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_IS_LOADING:
      return state.set('isLoading', action.value);
      ...
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const AppReducer = combineReducers({
  nav,
  store,
});

export default AppReducer;
```

and file i call DraweOpen:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/dist/MaterialIcons";
import { DrawerBurger } from "../common/styles";
import { navigate } from "../store/actions";

const drawerButton = (props) => (
  <DrawerBurger>
    <TouchableOpacity 
      onPress={() => props.navigate("DrawerOpen")}
    >
      <Icon name="menu" size={30} color="white" />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </DrawerBurger>
);

drawerButton.propTypes = {
  navigate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  (
    bindActionCreators({
      navigate,
    }, dispatch)
  )
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(drawerButton);
```

and i call drawerButton component on navigation options like:

```
...
class Dashboard extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = () => ({
    headerTitle: <Header dashboard />,
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#2c4e0f' },
    headerLeft: <DrawerButton />,
  });
...
```

I followed instructions on reactnavigation.org, also read some example code to build navigator.

Actually there was no error before redux integration and the navigator structure was same except BackHandling.

Here is my actions.js:

```
import { NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
import {...} from './constants';

...
export const navigate = routeName => NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName });
```

My environment is:

- react-navigation: 1.5.11
- react-native: 0.53.0
- react-navigation-redux-helpers: 1.0.5
- react-redux: 5.0.7
- redux: 3.7.2
- node: 8.9.4
- npm: 5.6.0

Thank for your help.

Comment: Can I see your `reducers initialization file`, and also where you're calling `drawerOpen`

Comment: Error seems to be in your `DrawerView.js` so would be great to see it

Comment: @PritishVaidya i added related files to question. Thank you.

Comment: Can you also share your `actions` file?

Comment: @PritishVaidya added related action to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the redux integration [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/redux-integration.html), it seems you've missed one step.

You need to add `addNavigationHelpers` from **React Navigation**

**Usage**

```
import {addNavigationHelpers} from 'react-navigation';

 <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
        dispatch,
        state: nav,
        addListener,
      })} />
```

Comment: I read the docs but when i look the example which is [link](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/examples/ReduxExample/src/navigators/AppNavigator.js) they did not use addNavigationHelpers.

Anyway, it is working now, thank you very much.